# http status 500 spring webservice hibernate

Tags: java, spring, web-services, hibernate

I'm getting an status http 500, it says the server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request. But the apache log shows no errors at all.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tms"/>
            <beans:property name="username" value="postgres"/>
            <beans:property name="password" value="paswoord"/>
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <beans:property name="configLocation">
                <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="configurationClass">
                <beans:value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</beans:value>
            </beans:property>
            <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
                <beans:props>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
                    <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                </beans:props>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven />
        <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
        </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="be.pxl.publictms" />
</beans:beans>
```

testController the getUsers method works partly i can print the results but it won't return it as an populated list.

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import be.pxl.publictms.model.Computer;
import be.pxl.publictms.pojo.Gebruiker;
import be.pxl.publictms.service.GebruikerService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("test")
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private GebruikerService gebruikerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "pc",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Computer testMethod() {
        return new Computer(0, "DELL");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "users",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Gebruiker> getUsers(){
        List<Gebruiker> users = gebruikerService.getGebruikers();
        System.out.println("***********************************************");
        for(Gebruiker user: users){
            System.out.println(user.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("***********************************************");
        /*List<Gebruiker> users = new ArrayList<Gebruiker>();
        users.add(new Gebruiker(1, "laurens", "test"));
        users.add(new Gebruiker(2, "laurens", "test"));
        users.add(new Gebruiker(3, "laurens", "test"));*/
        return users;
    }
}
```

GebruikerService:

```
import be.pxl.publictms.DAO.GebruikerDAO;
import be.pxl.publictms.pojo.Gebruiker;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 *
 * @author 11302785
 */
@Service
public class GebruikerServiceImpl implements GebruikerService{

    @Autowired
    private GebruikerDAO gebruikerDao;

    @Transactional
    public void addGebruiker(Gebruiker gebruiker) {
        gebruikerDao.addGebruiker(gebruiker);
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<Gebruiker> getGebruikers() {
        return gebruikerDao.getGebruikers();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteGebruiker(int id) {
        gebruikerDao.deleteGebruiker(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateGebruiker(Gebruiker gebruiker) {
        gebruikerDao.updateGebruiker(gebruiker);
    }
}
```

gebruikerDAO:

```
import be.pxl.publictms.pojo.Gebruiker;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 *
 * @author 11302785
 */
@Repository
public class GebruikerDAOImpl implements GebruikerDAO{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public void addGebruiker(Gebruiker gebruiker) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(gebruiker);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Gebruiker> getGebruikers() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Gebruiker").list();
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteGebruiker(int id) {
        Gebruiker gebruiker = (Gebruiker)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(Gebruiker.class, id);
        if(null != gebruiker){
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(gebruiker);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateGebruiker(Gebruiker gebruiker) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(gebruiker);
    }

}
```

pojo class gebruiker (it's dutch, it meaning is User... sorry for the dutch parts in it):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Gebruiker generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Gebruiker  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int gebruikerid;
     private Werknemer werknemer;
     private String gebruikersnaam;
     private String paswoord;
     private Set<Bericht> berichtsForGebruikerid = new HashSet<Bericht>(0);
     private Set<Bericht> berichtsForOntvangerid = new HashSet<Bericht>(0);
    public Gebruiker() {
    }


    public Gebruiker(int gebruikerid, String gebruikersnaam, String paswoord) {
        this.gebruikerid = gebruikerid;
        this.gebruikersnaam = gebruikersnaam;
        this.paswoord = paswoord;
    }
    public Gebruiker(int gebruikerid, Werknemer werknemer, String gebruikersnaam, String paswoord, Set<Bericht> berichtsForGebruikerid, Set<Bericht> berichtsForOntvangerid) {
       this.gebruikerid = gebruikerid;
       this.werknemer = werknemer;
       this.gebruikersnaam = gebruikersnaam;
       this.paswoord = paswoord;
       this.berichtsForGebruikerid = berichtsForGebruikerid;
       this.berichtsForOntvangerid = berichtsForOntvangerid;
    }

    public int getGebruikerid() {
        return this.gebruikerid;
    }

    public void setGebruikerid(int gebruikerid) {
        this.gebruikerid = gebruikerid;
    }
    public Werknemer getWerknemer() {
        return this.werknemer;
    }

    public void setWerknemer(Werknemer werknemer) {
        this.werknemer = werknemer;
    }
    public String getGebruikersnaam() {
        return this.gebruikersnaam;
    }

    public void setGebruikersnaam(String gebruikersnaam) {
        this.gebruikersnaam = gebruikersnaam;
    }
    public String getPaswoord() {
        return this.paswoord;
    }

    public void setPaswoord(String paswoord) {
        this.paswoord = paswoord;
    }
    public Set<Bericht> getBerichtsForGebruikerid() {
        return this.berichtsForGebruikerid;
    }

    public void setBerichtsForGebruikerid(Set<Bericht> berichtsForGebruikerid) {
        this.berichtsForGebruikerid = berichtsForGebruikerid;
    }
    public Set<Bericht> getBerichtsForOntvangerid() {
        return this.berichtsForOntvangerid;
    }

    public void setBerichtsForOntvangerid(Set<Bericht> berichtsForOntvangerid) {
        this.berichtsForOntvangerid = berichtsForOntvangerid;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return this.gebruikersnaam + " " + this.paswoord;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which log are you looking at? On tomcat, you will need to look at `logs/catalina.out` unless you have your own logging.

Comment: i think i'm looking at the catalina log file, all the other errors that i came acros were displayed there also i added my own try catch in the getUser method but it didn't report anything .... The strang thing is that my list is getting populated, i can print it as well, but not returning it into a json list.

Comment: What is the output you're receiving? Can you post any errors that show up in the logs? Please change the logs to print debug statements as well.

Comment: You can get a 500 due to an unhandled exception too so maybe check the aoolicstion server logs if you have exceptions during startup or your application specific logs

Comment: the only error i get is from SLF4J that its nuable to load class "org.slf4j.impl.staticlogbiner" and an hibernate query: Hibernate: select gebruiker0_.gebruikerid as gebruike1_16_, gebruiker0_.werknemerid as werkneme2_16_, gebruiker0_.gebruikersnaam as gebruike3_16_, gebruiker0_.paswoord as paswoord16_ from public.gebruiker gebruiker0_

Comment: i'm going to try to fetch some more errors by looking at other logs...

Comment: i have looked at the catalina logs but there is absolutely nothing...